# sorting row in php query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with fields: id, number, title. It displays a list of sales. In one sale there may be several titles.
I have this code:

```
$todbprod = $mysqli->query('SELECT waybills.waybill_id AS id, waybills.goods_id AS number, nalvmag.name AS title
 FROM `waybills`, `nalvmag` 
 WHERE waybills.goods_id = nalvmag.id ORDER BY waybills.waybill_id');
while($row = $todbprod->fetch_array())
{

echo "sale: ".$row['id']."<br>\n";
echo "product: ".$row['number']."\n";
echo "name: ".$row['title']."<hr>\n"; 
}
```

Now it is output like this:

```
 - sale 01, title 01
 - sale 01, title 02
 - sale 01, title 03
 - sale 02, title 01
```

And I want to bring to the list:

```
 - sale 01
   - title 01
   - title 02
   - title 03
 - sale 02
   - title 01
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your result set is in sale-title order, you can try printing using the following logic:

If we hit a new sale not seen before, print that sale.
Always print a title, after a possible sale, if printed above.

```
$sale = NULL;
while ($row = $todbprod->fetch_array())
{
    $new_sale = $row['id'];
    if ($new_sale != $sale) {
        $sale = $new_sale;
        echo "sale: ".$sale."<br>\n";
    }
    echo "name:   ".$row['title']."<hr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array =  array(
        array('sale 01', 'title 01'),
        array('sale 01', 'title 02'),
        array('sale 01', 'title 03'),
        array('sale 02', 'title 01')
    );
$new = array();
foreach($array as $row){
    $new[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
```

$new contains array you want....